# Can a Discord bot get back its own message ID and then delete it in another function?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I was thinking and my question is, for example:
Imagine creating a **bot that plays music** from a folder, a user joins this voice channel - then the bot joins triggered by a **!play** command - sending a message that *"xy is playing xy.mp3"*, but when the user (**or all users**) leave the voice channel the **bot stops the music and leaves**. After the bot leaves **it should delete the message it has sent** (*"x user playing y.mp3"*), for that it needs its **own message id** to delete it after leaving. Is that possible?

Comment: Can a bot get its own message? Yes. Can it execute code when a user leaves the voice channel? Absolutely. Put those two together, and it becomes a bit silly to question if it's even *possible* - of course it is, most things are in programming.

Comment: I think this question isn't well formed right now. It should present a clear problem and a clear question about the problem that has good objectively correct answers. Please add your attempt at implementing this feature and ask a question about something you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible!

Try this:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new discord.Client();

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    msg.delete();
  }, 5000);
});

client.login(/* Your token */);
```

What this will do is delete the message after 5000ms (5 seconds).

If you want to delete the message in an external function you need to save the message id, fetch it later and delete the fetched message.